# PHP Email entire page without OB

Tags: php, javascript, email

I have a page that doubles as the print page and email version of a page on our website. The page cannot be found by the user but loads in an iframe and either prints or emails depending on what button the user pressed to load it via GET. ie. `?purpose=print ?purpose=email`

Now the print function triggers JS window.pint() whereas the email function uses PHP html mail. In order to get the contents of the entire page I used OB functions

```
ob_end_start();
// page content
ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

This though is cowing up my print function and other JS on the page. Is there another way of getting the content of the page and passing it to the `$message` parameter of the email?

Any ideas,

Marvellous

Comment: what's the problem with JS functions? your print function gets never executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean using the OB functions affects the proper display of your page?

Have you tried something like that:

```
ob_end_start();
// page content
if(!empty($_GET['purpose']) && $_GET['purpose'] == "email") {
    $message = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    // your code for sending the $message
} else {
    ob_end_flush();
}
```

What this does is output the page normally if `purpose` is not set or is something other than "email". If you want to send the email **and** display the content, then just replace `ob_end_clean` with `ob_end_flush` (in that case you don't need the if-condition).

Comment: Yes exactly it does not render the page correctly. The problem though is that both functions EMAIL and PRINT require that some javascript is triggered from the iframe to the parent document and that is not rendering properly either

Comment: Done. I have moved the scripts to the top of the page before the OB_START with window load function attached to them.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use JS to render this page.

That would be easiest solution.

I see no problem here though. You need content and you obviously have a content. Just send it then

Answer (score -2):

yes, use [curl()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), save the page-contents (the return-body) and send it by mail. That should work better than the ob_*-functions.